# Compare two classes with range of Marks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with two classes (A or B) and marks and I want to present the mark ranges per class.

Dataframe:

```
Class Mark  Department       
A     74.0  1 
A     73.0  2   
B     72.0  1
A     75.0  1
B     64.0  2
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Class Mark Range        
A     73.0-75.0        
B     64.0-72.0
```

and I was thinking of using the min max (creating a new field for the range). But as a start, I tried to just group it:

```
df['count'] = 1
result = df.pivot_table('count', index='Mark', columns='Class', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

which is complex and I abandoned this quickly.

I then I only kept two columns in my dataframe (Mark and Class) and used the following:

```
df[['Mark','Class']].values
```

And now I just have to create the Mark range column. I was thinking whether there was a simpler way without the steps to simply pivot the data and check the range (min max of columnA grouped by ColumnB).

Comment: `df.groupby('Class').Mark.agg(['min','max'])`?

Comment: only thing missing is the range concat, have any idea on how to do it nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `GroupBy.apply` and get the `max` and `min` per group and represent them as string with `f-strings`:

```
df = (
    df.groupby('Class')['Mark'].apply(lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}')
      .reset_index(name='Mark Range')
)

  Class Mark Range
0  A     73.0-75.0
1  B     64.0-72.0
```

Comment: I like this a lot, great idea to use f-strings

Comment: This works handy, especially if I want to add more dimensions (e.g. Department). ```df.groupby(['Class','Department'])['Mark'].apply(lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}')
      .reset_index(name='MarkRange')```

Answer (score 2):

Simple but ugly:

```
temp = df.groupby('Class')['Mark'].agg({'min': min, 'max': max})
temp['range'] = temp['min'].map(str) + '-' + temp['max'].map(str)
```

Result of doing `temp[['range']]`:

```
           range
Class           
A      73.0-75.0
B      64.0-72.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using `pivot_table`:

```
df_new = (df.pivot_table('Mark', 'Class', aggfunc=lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}')
            .add_suffix(' Range').reset_index())

Out[1543]:
  Class Mark Range
0     A  73.0-75.0
1     B  64.0-72.0
```

---

As in your comment. To add `Deparment`, just use the list `['Class', 'Department']` for `index` as follows

```
df_new = (df.pivot_table('Mark', ['Class', 'Department'], 
                          aggfunc=lambda x: f'{x.min()}-{x.max()}')
            .add_suffix(' Range').reset_index())

Out[259]:
  Class  Department Mark Range
0     A           1  74.0-75.0
1     A           2  73.0-73.0
2     B           1  72.0-72.0
3     B           2  64.0-64.0
```

Comment: That works for one dimension. But if I want to add 'Department', I struggled a bit

Comment: @ApoloRadomer: IIUC, it is not difficult to add `Department`. I edited the answer to add it. Check the updated

Comment: Yeah. I did that. I had to re-run Jupyter and it worked.